# Finding the format of a struct.pack() string

Tags: python

Say I have a packed string such as

```
"\xe2\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Hello World!\x01\x1f\x85\xebQ\xb8\x1e\t@"
```

and I don't know the format it was packed using. Is there any way to find the format it was packed with using only that string? If there isn't any way to find the format, what is the best way to guess the format?

NOTE: The packed string above was packed like so:

```
struct.pack("<q12s?d", 482, "Hello World!", True, 3.14)
```

Comment: There's no way of being sure. You could guess (totally or partially) but there are no guarantees, mainly because there are multiple values that when packed generate the same outputs.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok then. What is the best way to guess the format?

Comment: With no prior knowledge?  Impossible.